# How can i call the method to the stats in the array and print it

Tags: java

```
 public static int Class() {

        System.out.println("Character Types");

        List<String> chaName = Arrays.asList("Wizard", "Sorcerer", "Monk", "Cleric", "Warlock",
                "Druid", "Rouge", "Bard", "Fighter", "Ranger", "Paladin", "Barbarian");
        int[] characterDiceValue = new int[]{6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 12};

        chaName.forEach(s -> System.out.println("\t" + s));
        index = -1;
        do {
            System.out.println("Select a Character name from the given list above");
            characterClass = sc.next();
        }
        while ((index = chaName.indexOf(characterClass)) == -1);    
        characterDiceValue[index] = hitDice;
        return hitDice;
    }

 public static int rollDice() {

        int dice1 = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 % hitDice + 1);
        int dice2 = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 % hitDice + 1);
        int dice3 = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 % hitDice + 1);
        int dice4 = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 % hitDice + 1);
        int total;
        if (dice1 < dice2 && dice1 < dice3 && dice1 < dice4) {
            total = dice2 + dice3 + dice4;
        } else if (dice2 < dice3 && dice2 < dice4) {
            total = dice1 + dice3 + dice4;
        } else if (dice3 < dice4) {
            total = dice1 + dice2 + dice4;
        } else {
            total = dice1 + dice2 + dice3;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

This is just a part of the code. In the roll dice method four dices are rolled and lowest value is suspended and the total is calculated. The dice types are given in the Class method and when the user selects a character name, the relevant dice type of that name is rolled. Then I need to assign those total to the variables in the array and calculate the bonus for it. In this code the output i'm getting is zero to all the variables. How can i fix this.

Comment: What is the value of `hitDice`?

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem, and if you can reduce it to ten lines or less, I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Sorry i put the wrong part of the code. The hitDice is generated from Class method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this code the output i'm getting is zero to all the variables. How
>   can i fix this.

The variables depend upon the correct value of `hitDice`, which is not properly getting assigned by the method `Class()`.

The reason you are getting this behaviour is the following line in `Class()`

```
characterDiceValue[index] = hitDice;
```

This does not assign the correct value to hitDice.  The only explanation for your results is that early in the program, the static variable `hitDice` must have been assigned to zero.

The fix is to correctly assign:

```
hitDice = characterDiceValue[index];
return hitDice;
```

After this, you will get the desired results.